# EXCEL array formula to indicate if a value in one range is present in another range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a list of values in column A, and another list of values in column B.

I am trying to have a single cell in column C indicate TRUE if any value in column A is in Column B, or FALSE is no value in column A is in Column B.

I tried MATCH(lookup value, in range), but that only looks at one value in A.

Is it possible to do this without VBA? Open to VBA solutions also. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty UDF that will do it.

```
Public Function Exist(a As Range, b As Range) As Boolean
Dim temp As Boolean
temp = False
For Each cel In a
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(b, cel.value) > 0 Then
        temp = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next cel

exist = temp

End Function
```

Comment: This code seems to give wrong results. If I manual use the formula `=countif(B4, AIP!A:A)` i get 1 but calling your function as `Exist(B3:B4, AIP!A:A)` i get false. And sense i know B3 does not exist in the range, but b4 does, I expect to get True. I'm wondering also if it makes sense to end the countif loop as soon as 1 cell evaluates to true.

Comment: @Britt Huh, that's interesting,  I have tested it on my machine and it works.  Any chance I could get a copy of the data to test.  My email is scott.craner@gmail.com.  Also in your question you stated that you wanted one cell to return true if there was any cells in one range that equals any cell in another range, so there is no point continuing the loop if a 'True' is found.

Comment: The problem was the word 'Exists'.  Once changed to 'Exist', which is what I had on my workbook but changed in the answer, the function worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've used something like this to compare values in one list to another in VBA. Could take a while if you have a lot of values to check. Just set the B range to however large the range is on your sheet.

```
Option Explicit
Dim Index As Long
Dim valueFound As Range
Sub compareAandB()

Index = 2

Do While ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Index, 1) <> ""

    Set valueFound = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B1000").Find(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Index, 1))

    If valueFound Is Nothing Then
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Index, 3) = "Not Found"
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Index, 3) = "Found"
    End If
    Index = Index + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, if it is VBA, it needs to take arguments something like isPresent(lookUpValues As Range, lookHere As Range). I have to use this formula/function 924 times in my workbook.